# I open Telnet, but I still can't connect

Tags: telnet

I want to check an HTTP response message,(I should have seen a response message that includes the base HTML file), with this

> To telnet into your favorite Web server. Type in a one-line
>   request message for some object that is housed on the server: for
>   example:
>
> telnet cis.poly.edu 80
>
> GET /~ross/ HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: cis.poly.edu

First, I tried to do this using cmd:

- I type `telnet`,
- after that i type `o`
- then `cis.poly.edu 80`

After this, I get `connecting to cis.poly.edu...` this never changes, it doesn't even say it failed connection!

Also, I tried this http://windows7themes.net/how-to-telnet-in-windows-7.html but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Alternative, install fiddler; http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ run it then simply open the url in your browser, fiddler will display the complete set of data associated with the request

Comment: You should use curl (http://curl.haxx.se/; `curl -v http://cis.poly.edu/~/ross`) for this sort of thing.

Comment: It is a prompt that waits for you to input a Request manually. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/670866/feeding-contents-of-a-text-file-as-command-to-telnet) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Telnet on Windows by default does not "echo" what you type -- just type the relative URL to what you want, and you should get the HTML page -- or a HTTP status code such as 404.

Example: GET /index.html

Comment: u mean i type "GET /index.html" in cmd ?

still not working!

Answer (score 1):

The host cis.poly.edu seems to have moved on to bigger and better things than serving web pages. Try using a host that you know is running a web server.