# How to download a file through Telnet using HTTP request?

Tags: networking, http, telnet, cmd.exe, network-protocols

I need to download a file, for example: http://gensho.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/7.5.0/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-7.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso with usage of Telnet and HTTP request. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried simply using TELNET to connect and typing:
get <address>?

Comment: @JTYoerger - I was missing double entering and telnet was just prompting for more.

Comment: These might help.. googling telnet run command output to file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970530/telnet-output-save-it-to-file-using-bat-file  and http://superuser.com/questions/670866/feeding-contents-of-a-text-file-as-command-to-telnet

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you need to use telnet? It's a terrible method to do this. What restricts you from using something designed for this task, e.g. `curl` or `wget`?

Comment: No, this actually is not a XY problem. I was curious how HTTP request looks, with usage of different tools. While I was trying to connect and download the file I was running Wireshark and I saw how it looks like. I wanted to check also, what happens, when for example, I turn off my router and turn on again (how does error frame looks like etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It has to be Telnet.

Okay, so I figured it out.

```
telnet gensho.acc.umu.se 80
GET /debian-cd/7.5.0/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-7.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso HTTP/1.0
```

and double press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (that was the part I was missing, the second press of Enter will retrieve data)

However, that still doesn't get this data into a file, (so almost there but not quite)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Unfortunately, asking other questions in an answer is discouraged. Feel free to ask a new question, and link to this one, to ask the second part.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: @JTYoerger  He only partially figured it out. He wants it in a file. See his original answer before  Luke edited it. Or see the line I added back with an amendment.

Comment: To get that into a file, you need to pipe the output into a buffer. Telnet is an interactive program designed for remote shells. It is not designed for file retrieval. That's what FTP was (is) for, and what programs like `wget` and `curl` do. I do not know of any way with just `telnet.exe` to do what you want, because that's not what it's designed for.

Comment: @MarkHenderson I haven't tried these but see my comment to his question which gives two links that may help  do it

Answer (score 0):

Does it HAVE to be telnet?  cURL would do a much better, and well designed, job at doing this:

curl -O gensho.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/7.5.0/amd64/iso-dvd/debian-7.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

Comment: Agreed, curl is the way to go.  It's brain dead simple.